# Tableau 10.2+ compatibility with WDC

Tags: tableau-api

I am currently using `tableauwdc-1.1.0` with Tableau versions 9.x and 10.1.  In order to use Tableau 10.2+, will I need to create a new WDC with `tableauwdc-2.x.x`?  There seems to be conflicting information online and in the official documentation

So far I've seen:

https://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/news/

> Important: This is a breaking change. Existing connectors will
>   continue to work in future versions of Tableau. However, if you link
>   an existing connector to version 2.0 of the WDC API, then you will
>   have to update the connector to use the new API.

http://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/docs/wdc_faq#can-i-still-use-version-10-of-the-wdc-api-where-can-i-find-information-about-version-10-of-the-wdc

> If you are creating a new connector for Tableau 10.0 or later, you
>   should use version 2 of the WDC API. However, version 1.0 of the WDC
>   API will continue to work in Tableau 10.0. Additionally, Tableau 9.3
>   and earlier only support version 1.0 of the WDC API.

which seems to support backwards compatibility, but https://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/docs/wdc_library_versions seems to imply that I would need to update the WDC.

Which one is correct?  Thanks for the help